# Errors on deployng project with npm react-animated-number and @emotion/react

Tags: reactjs, npm, module, package, netlify

I'm trying to deploy a project on Netlify but I'm always getting this error:

```
npm ERR! While resolving: react-animated-number@0.4.4
```

I already have try:

```
npm i react-animated-number --legacy-peer-deps

npm i @emotion/react --legacy-peer-deps
```

But the error is still the same..

Could be the packages that I'm using?

Any solution??

Comment: try to install `npm i react-animated-number@0.4.4` at your server

Comment: what it shows you when you try `npm i react-animated-number --legacy-peer-deps`

Comment: @monim when I install with legacy peer doesn't show any error msg.. just when I try to deploy..